# Apache Camel route and Spring boot: application startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a Spring Boot (v. 1.5.1) application.

As part of the application's startup, it needs to call an external service. This is fine - I've implemented a class that implements ApplicationListener and the external service gets called correctly.

My issue is that the external service immediately calls my application back on a callback URL. That call to my application is failing with a 404 Not Found. The URL endpoint is set up as an Apache Camel (v. 2.17.0) route. As the external service is getting a 404, this would imply that the route hasn't been started in my application by the time that the external service calls it.

Indeed, I have pretty much proved this by debugging the application and adding a breakpoint prior to the call to the external service. If I call the callback URL myself with the code paused, I get a 404 myself. It isn't until the entirety of the ApplicationListener class' method has been completed and my application fully started up (message: "FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed") that the callback URL becomes available.

Is there any way that I can get the Apache Camel route to start prior to the call to the external service being made?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by transferring the ApplicationListener code to a new Camel Route which is configured to start after the callback URL route. It runs by means of a Camel timer.